# Конфликт YII CMemCache и Memcached

Tags: memcached, php, yii

Добрый день!

Есть такая проблема. Использую YII на сайте. настройки конфига выглядят так

```
   'cache'=>array(
        'class'=>'CMemCache',
        'useMemcached'=>true,
        'serializer' => false,
        'servers' => array(
            array('host' => 'localhost', 'port' => 11211, 'weight'=>60),
        )
    ),
```

Размещаю переменную в кеш памяти так

```
\Yii::app()->cache->set("racerUser-" . $this->sid, json_encode($racer), 3600);
```

Затем в контроллере и методах читаю ее так

```
$sesUser = \Yii::app()->cache->get("racerUser-" . $this->sid);
```

Переменная читается, данные получаются.

Теперь проблема:
Когда эту же самую переменную пытаюсь получить не из YII

```
$mem = new Memcached();
$mem->addServer("localhost", "11211", 60);
var_dump($mem->getAllKeys()); die();
```

Я эту переменную уже не вижу... В чем проблема? Бьюсь 2 дня...

Спасибо!

Comment: Memcached разделяет приложения, не знаю сам механизм, но он это делает. Зачем вы пытаетесь достать эту переменную не из Yii?

Comment: @Fike ну например один скрипт туда пишет, а совершенно другой(-ие) так же используют эти данные?

Comment: Есть такая необходимость.. Есть С++ часть работающая с мемкешем. И есть PHP часть работающая с мемкешем. Они не видят обьекты друг друга... После изысканий я понял что мемкеш переменную YII не видет даже пых причем того же самого сайта при обращении через стандартный Memcash.

Comment: @BlackWidow, а сейчас не могу найти где это я прочитал, так что может я наврал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел! Это не memcached разделяет приложения, а обертка Yii над всеми кэшами (CCache):

```
function set() {
    ...
    return $this->setValue($this->generateUniqueKey($id), $value, $expire);
}
```

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/caching/CCache.php#L185
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/caching/CCache.php#L94

Т.о. уникальный ключ у вас скорее всего один из двух:

```
Yii::app()->id.$id
md5(Yii::app()->id.$id)
```

Comment: хм, неслабая подстава. т.о. получается, что из внешнего приложения не разберешься где что?

Comment: @thunder с т.з. большинства все правильно (не приходится беспокоиться за совместный доступ), но я на эти же грабли наступал, когда по каким-то соображениям менял Id приложения на странице, и у меня отваливались куки вместе с авторизацией. У Yii вообще местами странная логика, взять хотя бы их первый coding convention. Но в принципе для этого и нужна система issue на гитхабе )  
Что до конкретного случая - сделайте консольную команду, которая будет дампать айди приложения и настройку мемкэша (хэшировать ли ключ), при запуске с++ запускайте ее и сканируйте вывод.

Comment: @Fike я не ТС, так, интересующийся :) Сейчас мемкеш используют только из одного приложения на перле, в дальнейшем теже данные будут использоваться и другим приложением уже на пхп под Silex... Надо будет у них в коде посмотреть такие грабли... Но все равно спасибо, я б тоже наверное не один час сидел и пытался понять в чем проблема :)

Comment: Спасибо! Круто! Поставил "правильный" :)

Comment: @thunder попутал )

Answer (score 0):

проблема в том, что getAllKeys не возвращает все ключи. Там лимит есть.

> Memcached::getAllKeys() queries each memcache server and retrieves an array of all keys stored on them at that point in time. This is not an atomic operation, so it isn't a truly consistent snapshot of the keys at point in time. As memcache doesn't guarantee to return all keys you also cannot assume that all keys have been returned.

Попробуйте по ключу достать значение.

Comment: возвращает return(false) в то время как YII возвращает обьект